# Basic R Syntax - Boolean and Max

Tags: r

I need help with a exercise question using R

Assuming the number of shoes equals 10, price of a shoe is $100, and therefore total cost of a shoe is $1000.

Create a Boolean variable too_expensive, set to True if the cost is greater than $1000.
Create a variable max_shoes, which is the number of shoes you can afford for $1000.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to get your homework done for you. Please show us at least what you have tried and where you're stuck or a concrete problem arises - then formulate this into a precise question with some sample code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need something like below?

```
n <- 10
p <- 100

too_expense <- n*p>1000
max_shoes <- 1000/p
```